# How can I composite Quartz and OpenGL / Metal drawing efficiently?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, quartz-2d, metal

I have a game that will require some high level drawing constructs like complex bezier curves and fills (varying with each frame) that I'd like to composite / overlay with some more primitive stuff drawn in OpenGL or Metal.  Is there an efficient (high performance) way to do this?

1. Can I simply have a quartz drawing layer over the OpenGL layer or will this suffer a huge performance hit?
2. Should I capture my Quartz drawing to a bitmap and push it into OpenGL as a texture? Or would doing this on every frame be prohibitively slow?
3. Can I go the other way and capture my OpenGL rendering into a bitmap that I draw with Quartz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to overlay a quartz view on top of an opengl view without (seemingly) too great of a performance hit.  I was not actually able to figure out how to do this in Interface Builder but it was easy enough in code by simply creating a "master" view controller and procedurally adding the two views as sub-views something like this:

```
let glkViewController = GLKViewController()
self.view.addSubview( glkViewController!.view )

let overlayView = OverlayView()
overlayView.opaque = false
overlayView.frame = self.view.frame
let overlayViewController = OverlayViewController()
overlayViewController.view = overlayView
self.view.addSubview(overlayView)
overlayViewController.viewDidLoad()
```

Note that the glk view has its own refresh loop and the above assumes that you set up a CADisplayLink or other run loop for your quartz view controller in the viewDidLoad().  It is not necessary to call / refresh between the two.  The glk view seems to refresh on the default `NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop()` so if you use that they will compete for time and it seems that the opengl loop wins if things get strained.  You can easily create a separate loop or background thread for your overlay to separate them.